# use a default constructor plus Fragment при компиляции

Tags: android

У меня есть приложение, при компиляции apk выдает ошибку в фрагменте (при обычном запуске в эмуляторе все хорошо):

> Error:Error: Avoid non-default constructors in fragments: use a default constructor plus Fragment#setArguments(Bundle) instead [ValidFragment]

Вот сам фрагмент:

```
public class CreatePage_Fragment extends Fragment {

    ...

    public CreatePage_Fragment(String str, int page) {

        ...
        ...
        ...

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        boolean condition;

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.table, container, false);

        ...   
        ...
        ...

        return view;   
    }

    public void onLongClicked(int position, int form, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list, int positionInList) {

        ...
        ...
        ...

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, Menu.NONE, R.string.context_menu_item_1);
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 2, Menu.NONE, R.string.context_menu_item_3);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        ...
        ...
        ...

        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Как исправить ошибку и из-за чего она?

Comment: гугло-переводчиком пробовали пользоваться? =)

Comment: При поворотах устройства для переинициализации фрагмента системой вызывается конструктор по умолчанию (без параметров). В этом случае данные, передаваемые через конструктор будут утрачены, что, скорее всего, приведет к ошибке или неправильной работе фрагмента. Потому конструкторов с парамертрами в фрагментах следует избегать всеми способами.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, в том то и проблема что гугло-переводчиком - да...

Comment: @pavlofff, спасибо! Толково объяснили, все стало понятно. Если не секрет, где Вы об этом узнали (книга или оф. доки)?

Comment: Об этом сказано в [документации](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) - *All subclasses of Fragment must include a public no-argument constructor. The framework will often re-instantiate a fragment class when needed, in particular during state restore, and needs to be able to find this constructor to instantiate it.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дословный перевод:

> Избегайте конструкторов с параметрами для фрагментов. Вместо них используйте конструктор по умолчанию вместе с методом `setArguments(Bundle)`.

Что означает, что передавать какие-либо данные во фрагмент надо через `Bundle`, а не через аргументы конструктора. Такой способ связан с особенностями жизненного цикла фрагмента.

*Согласно @pavlofff и документации:*

> All subclasses of Fragment must include a public no-argument constructor. The framework will often re-instantiate a fragment class when needed, in particular during state restore, and needs to be able to find this constructor to instantiate it.

Т.е:

> При поворотах устройства для переинициализации фрагмента системой вызывается конструктор по умолчанию (без параметров). В этом случае данные, передаваемые через конструктор будут утрачены, что, скорее всего, приведет к ошибке или неправильной работе фрагмента. Потому конструкторов с парамертрами в фрагментах следует избегать всеми способами.

---

Передавать данные во фрагмент с помощью `Bundle` надо так:

```
FragmentClass fragment = new FragmentClass();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("key", "value");
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Получать их во фрагменте уже так:

```
// в onCreate, onActivityCreated и прочих методах жизненного цикла фрагмента
String srt = this.getArguments().getString("key");
```

Comment: @Etki, теперь перевод не дословный получился)

Comment: Совсем не дословный... :)